# Can't understand the return condition

Tags: python

```
def remove_repeated_characters(tokens):
    repeat_pattern = re.compile(r'(\w*)(\w)\2(\w*)')
    match_substitution = r'\1\2\3'
    
    def replace(old_word):
        if wordnet.synsets(old_word):
            return old_word
        new_word = repeat_pattern.sub(match_substitution, old_word)
        return replace(new_word) if new_word != old_word else new_word
            
    correct_tokens = [replace(word) for word in tokens]
    return correct_tokens
```

I don't understand the return condition of the `replace` function, can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

it just means

```
if new_word != old_word:
    return replace(new_word)
else:
    return new_word
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def func(x):
    return 'Yes' if x < 5 else 'No'


for i in range(10):
    print(func(i), end=' ')

print()


def func_new(x):
    if x < 5:
        return "Yes"
    else:
        return "No"


for i in range(10):
    print(func_new(i), end=' ')

>>>Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes No No No No No
>>>Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes No No No No No
```

The condition there means:

```
if new_word != old_word:
   return replace(new_word)
else:
   return new_word
```